# Postgresql installation, avoid creating “postgres” user

Tags: postgresql, linux, installation, postgresql-9.4

I have a constraint, that I can use only one user on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.

Now, I need to install PostgreSQL 9.4. Is it possible to somehow avoid the automatic creation of "postgres" linux user by PostgreSQL's installation wizard, and use current user as a database admin?

Additional explanation about the weird  constraints:

We have to host our software on the server of the IT company, which is subsidiary of the big bank. They have quite strict rules, due to storing and processing of the sensitive user data. So, one of the rules, is that we can have only one user there and everything should be installed under this user (with sudo rights). Initially, the server has only the most basic software (and PostgreSQL is not included there).

Comment: Could you describe a bit why this (very weird) constraint is in place?  Is there any other user there than `root`?

Comment: @dezso, we have to host our software on the server of the IT company, which is subsidiary of the big bank. They have quite strict rules, due to storing and processing of the sensitive user data.
So, one of the rules, is that we can have only one user there and everything should be installed under this user (with sudo rights).
Initially, the server has only the most basic software (and PostgreSQL is not included there).

Comment: But you can install software on it? I would expect them to provide you with the installation in that case.

Comment: Is docker an alternative or do you really have to install it?

Comment: What flavour of Linux (Debian, Redhat, CentOS, Ubuntu, ...)?

Comment: And (irrelevant to the issue but) why 9.4 and not the latest version (10)? Why a version that is 3 versions behind?

Comment: .. and soon to be 4 ...

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11

Comment: @TomV, I have asked, they do not support Docker, so it's not an alternative.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, from the [PostgreSQL website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/suse/) I understood, that SUSE 11 supports latest 9.4 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is in this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/929677/postgresql-installation-avoid-creating-postgres-user

The only way is to build PostgreSQL from source.